# How can I make dynamic progress bar using just jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wrote a code for progressbar using jquery it works as expect but if I add second element all element works same that is why I guess I have to make it dynamic but I have no idea to do how can I make it as dynamic ?

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="trustyou-progressbar pull-right">
            <p class="trustyou-puan">100/72 Puan</p>
            <div class="progressFill">
                <span class="ani-puan" ani-puan="72"></span>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="trustyou-progressbar pull-right">
            <p class="trustyou-puan">100/39 Puan</p>
            <div class="progressFill">
                <span class="ani-puan" ani-puan="39"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.trustyou-progressbar{
  width:100px;
}
.trustyou-puan{
    font-size: 13px;
    color:#494949;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.progressFill{
    width:100%;
    height:6px;
    background:#222222;
}
.ani-puan{
    display:block;
    height:100%;
}
```

JQUERY

```
 var getprogressPuan = $('.ani-puan').attr('ani-puan');
  $(".ani-puan").css("width",getprogressPuan+"%");
  if((getprogressPuan>0) && (getprogressPuan<=40)){
      $(".ani-puan").css("background","#ca2424");
  }else if((getprogressPuan>=40) && (getprogressPuan<75)){
      $(".ani-puan").css("background","#d6d824");
  }else if((getprogressPuan>=75)){
      $(".ani-puan").css("background","#9ad204");
  }
```

[click to see demo](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/ALdVwZ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an iterator to apply your function to all elements:

```
$('.ani-puan').each(function() {

  var getprogressPuan = $(this).attr('ani-puan');
  $(this).css("width", getprogressPuan + "%");
  if ((getprogressPuan > 0) && (getprogressPuan <= 40)) {
    $(this).css("background", "#ca2424");
  } else if ((getprogressPuan >= 40) && (getprogressPuan < 75)) {
    $(this).css("background", "#d6d824");
  } else if ((getprogressPuan >= 75)) {
    $(this).css("background", "#9ad204");
  }

});
```

[Here is the sample page](http://codepen.io/monica_eds/pen/xEzWRE)

Answer (score 0):

here is the codepen link:http://codepen.io/kofijita/pen/WGyzQY

the $(".ani-puan") will get two elements , you should use iterator to differ them.

```
var $puan = $('.ani-puan');
for (var i = 0, len = $puan.length; i < len; i++) {
    var $cur = $('.ani-puan').eq(i);
    var getprogressPuan = $cur.attr('ani-puan');
    $cur.css("width", getprogressPuan + "%");
    if ((getprogressPuan > 0) && (getprogressPuan <= 40)) {
        $cur.css("background", "#ca2424");
    } else if ((getprogressPuan >= 40) && (getprogressPuan < 75)) {
        $cur.css("background", "#d6d824");
    } else if ((getprogressPuan >= 75)) {
        $cur.css("background", "#9ad204");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code just changes all elements with ani-puan class.

You need to create a jQuery component (a widget) to work with each progressbar separately.

Start by reading [How to Create a Basic Plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) and then you can study [jQuery UI's progressbar source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/widgets/progressbar.js) to see how they do it.

*If you don't mind, you can [download the jQuery UI progressbar](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.12.1&components=100000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000) (you don't need whole jQuery UI) and just change what you need.*

Also note that HTML5 already contain component [progress](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_progress.asp) that already does what you need (including changing the colors).

Answer (score 0):

You can also create Progress bar easily like this:

```js
var i = 0;
var clear = setInterval(function(){
  i++;
  $('.progressFill').text(i+'0%');
  $('.progressFill').width(i+'0%');
  if(i==10)
  {
      clearInterval(clear);
  }
},1000);
```

```css
.trustyou-progressbar{
 width: 100px;
 background-color: #000000;
}
.trustyou-puan{
    font-size: 13px;
    color:#494949;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.progressFill{
    width: 0%;
  height: 6px;
  background: #15D318;
}
.ani-puan{
    display:block;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="trustyou-progressbar pull-right">
   <div class="progressFill">
    <span class="ani-puan" ani-puan="72"></span>
   </div>
  </div>
   
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```